# Why isn't my script inverting all poses from all keyframes?

Tags: animation, scripting

the code works great placing all poses at same position but for some reason it doesn't paste flipped. Any ideas?

```
import bpy
import math

ctx = bpy.context
ops = bpy.ops
obj = ctx.object

ctx.scene.frame_start = 0
ctx.scene.frame_end = 1229
ctx.scene.frame_current = 0

for i in range(400):
    ctx.scene.frame_current = i
    obj.location.x = 0
    obj.location.y = 0
    ops.pose.loc_clear()
    ops.pose.copy()
    ops.pose.paste(flipped=True)
    ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='LocRotScale')
```

Comment: Use `scene.frame_set(frame)` to change frames.  What error message are you recieving?

Comment: it doesn't throw an error, it copies the first frame for all the next ones without inverting the pose.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, have you changed `scene.frame_current = i` to `scene.frame_set(i)`?

Comment: I did, it didn't make any difference